# BTRFS critical (device sda): corrupt leaf after mounting on Windows with WSL2

Tags: linux, data-recovery, btrfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, corruption

My question is as to the correct steps to attempt a fix of my BTRFS system, the possible cause and the place to report the problem.

---

**The Story**

I was playing around with the new *Windows Insider Build 20279* and the new possibility to mount BTRFS filesystem through WSL2 on Ubuntu 20.04.

I used one of my 2TB BTRFS external disks running in Single mode. The data on the disk is not that important but I would like to avoid having to restore it.

Following these instructions to mount it https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk, I was able to read the data and even write fine without any visible errors.

Then I tried running the scrub operation and that is where I got an error. The scrub was aborted but I could not find any error logs since I ran it from the Windows Properties tab. I decided to abort the mission, unmounted the disk and switched back to my good old Linux distro.

But when I try running the scrub here, it aborts, the disk switches to read only mode and I get the following errors:

```
Dec 31 11:07:06 kernel: BTRFS critical (device sda): corrupt leaf: block=52051968 slot=96 extent bytenr=311656448 len=16384 invalid generation, have 1319 expect (0, 1318]
Dec 31 11:07:06 kernel: BTRFS error (device sda): block=52051968 read time tree block corruption detected
```

Strangely though, I can still read the data fine (haven't checked checksums but haven't seen any obvious corruptions)

My question is, has anyone had a similar experience with BTRFS on Windows? Should I try and repair the BTRFS filesystem or should I just do a new `mkfs.btrfs`?

I already tried `btrfs check --repair` but it failed. The data is still readable but the errors are still present.

Also where can I report this issue to Microsoft?

Comment: Regarding issue reporting, I believe it should be https://github.com/microsoft/WSL.